# EAGLView: rotation doesn't change frame size

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I'm making OpenGL game and want to support both portrait and landscape orientations.
I wrote all necessary code to support autorotation and want to notify my game about viewport size change via

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: 
        @selector(orientationChanged:) 
        name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification 
        object: nil];
```

It rotates OK, but problem is that the image still renders vertically! I regenerate frame buffer by calling `layoutSubviews`. But these code returns vertical orientation

```
int width, height;
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES
     , GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &width);
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES
     , GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &height);
```

How can I set frame size to make image displayed correctly (horizontally)?

Comment: What to you do in your view controller (especially in `supportedInterfaceOrientations ` and `shouldAutorotate`)?

Comment: what'ss your view's autoresingMask?

Comment: @deko Please don't edit question title and add [SOLVED]. You could instead accept your answer to let community know you have found your solution.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra OK, I'll note that for the future and accept it in 2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED!

The solution was in setting UIView's autoresizeMask property

```
[self setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

Thanx for Daij-Djan!